# this regular expression's meaning

Tags: regex

I saw this in httpd.conf (of my mac)

```
#                                                                                                   
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being                              
# viewed by Web clients.                                                                            
#                                                                                                   
<FilesMatch "^\.([Hh][Tt]|[Dd][Ss]_[Ss])">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

that expression's former part(before or('|') sign) looks 'starting h or H, followed by T or t.
but what does latter part mean?
just 'starting D or d followed by S or s and underscore and S or s? then, what is that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `\.` means a literal `.`, so a match must start with a _period_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is used to match files like:

- .htaccess (Apache configuration)
- .DS_Store (Mac OS X Desktop Services Store file)

Comment: Thank you!!! (maybe other guys like me can read about that file here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store)

Answer (score 1):

This will match any file which begins with `.ht` or `.ds_s`, in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: wow! we gave the same answer (almost the same sentence) just a few seconds apart :)

Answer (score 0):

It matches anything starting either with ".ht" or ".ds_s" case insensitive.